# Dealing with date format in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a bunch of tweets which I have classified per topic. Having a dataset containing the date in this format `YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S` is there a way to plot the topics in time?

```
2020-11-02 07:45:47 | 1  #newest tweet
2020-11-03 09:41:10 | 5
2020-06-14 01:50:34 | 9  #oldest tweet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
df$V1 <- as.POSIXct(df$V1)
plot(df[order(df$V1), ])
```

[image]

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("2020-11-02 07:45:47", "2020-11-03 09:41:10",
"2020-06-14 01:50:34"), V2 = c(1L, 5L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```